# How to use internal integrated terminal instead PowerShell in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my other device, i using a terminal that provide by VSCode. But in my recent device, it use PowerShell. How can i use the internal terminal instead PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

1->Try changing your default shell from here [image]
2->click on **select default shell**

3->Then select the desired shell.
[image]

Comment: I mean, i want to use terminal that provided by VSCode. Using "ctrl+`" than using the terminal in VSCode. Not PowerShell, CMD, neither GitBash. https://imgur.com/a/UXJ0duy

Comment: @IlyaTrianggela follow these steps:

1-> go to preferences->settings

2-> type run in terminal

3-> Under the Run code confg->extensions -> check the "whether to run in integrated terminal" check box